# Fabric client application running on a docker container unable to connect to orderer container

Tags: java, docker, ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using fabric-samples 2.2 "test-network" application.
After starting up the network using fabric ca, I tried to connect from my sdk client application and send the transactions. But, I am getting error as it's unable to connect to orderer.
I am getting following exception

```
blockchainservice    | Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]

blockchainservice    |

blockchainservice    | org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel mychannel, send transaction failed on orderer OrdererClient{id: 9, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.example.com, url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:7050}. Reason: UNAVAILABLE: io exception

blockchainservice    | Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]

blockchainservice    |  at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendTransaction(OrdererClient.java:236) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0.jar!/:na]

blockchainservice    |  at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendTransaction(Orderer.java:164) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
```

and below are the logs from the orderer peer

```
2021-01-24 01:30:04.383 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 100 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: internal error server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.25.0.1:33964
```

**NOTE:- I am able to connect to the network and perform the transaction by running the client application from my local and cli. However, when I ran the same application from docker container its throwing error.**

Below is my networkconfig.yaml in client app

```
name: test-network-org1
version: 1.0.0
client:
  organization: Org1
  connection:
    timeout:
      peer:
        endorser: '300'

channels:
  mychannel:
    orderers:
      - orderer.example.com
    peers:
      peer0.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
      peer0.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    peers:
    - peer0.org1.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
    - ca.org1.example.com

orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:7050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /opt/app/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:7051
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /opt/app/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      hostnameOverride: peer0.org1.example.com
  peer0.org2.example.com:
    url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:9051
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /opt/app/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org2.example.com
      hostnameOverride: peer0.org2.example.com
certificateAuthorities:
  ca.org1.example.com:
    url: https://host.docker.internal:7054
    caName: ca-org1
    tlsCACerts:
      path: /opt/app/organizations/fabric-ca/org1/ca-cert.pem
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
```

Stack Trace in details at client application

```
2021-01-24 20:59:05.073 ERROR 1 --- [ault-executor-2] o.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient   : OrdererClient{id: 9, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.example.com, url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:7050}  managed channel isTerminated: false, isShutdown: false, state: TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2021-01-24 20:59:05.079 ERROR 1 --- [ault-executor-2] o.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient   : Received error org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient$1@5bad10f  UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-api-1.27.2.jar!/:1.27.2]]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1732) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:774) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1046) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:937) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1395) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:502) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:407) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address host.docker.internal found
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:165) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:101) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:429) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:255) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:701) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method) ~[netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.26.Final.jar!/:2.0.26.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:593) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1176) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1293) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1336) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:204) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1332) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2021-01-24 20:59:05.083 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient   : OrdererClient{id: 9, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.example.com, url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:7050} grpc status Code:io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0], Description UNAVAILABLE,

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1732) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:774) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1046) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:937) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1395) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:502) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:407) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address host.docker.internal found
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:165) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:101) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:429) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:255) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:701) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method) ~[netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.26.Final.jar!/:2.0.26.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:593) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1176) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1293) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1336) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:204) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1332) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2021-01-24 20:59:05.084 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient   : OrdererClient{id: 9, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.example.com, url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:7050}sendTransaction error Channel mychannel, send transaction failed on orderer OrdererClient{id: 9, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.example.com, url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:7050}. Reason: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]

org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel mychannel, send transaction failed on orderer OrdererClient{id: 9, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.example.com, url: grpcs://host.docker.internal:7050}. Reason: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendTransaction(OrdererClient.java:236) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendTransaction(Orderer.java:164) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.doSendTransaction(Channel.java:5686) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendTransaction(Channel.java:5533) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.TransactionImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionImpl.java:138) ~[fabric-gateway-java-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.TransactionImpl.submit(TransactionImpl.java:96) ~[fabric-gateway-java-2.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.dovetaillab.consentapi.blockchainservice.handler.Handler$submit$2.apply(Handler.kt:79) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dovetaillab.consentapi.blockchainservice.handler.Handler$submit$2.apply(Handler.kt:21) ~[classes!/:na]
```

Comment: refer this for your client application https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript and also this should be the format for your connection profile https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/organizations/ccp-template.yaml

Comment: Unlike the comment above, when I see it, There is no problem with the format of the `connection profile`. If the request was made to the orderer on `sendTransaction` but it was rejected, i will infer that the `transactionProposal` proceeded well and endorsing worked normally. Therefore, there was no problem on the peer side, the tls setting went well, and I will infer that there is no problem on the network. In the end, it seems that the reason why the TLS error occurred on the orderer can be accurately understood by referring to the configuration of the orderer.

Comment: Could you tell me the `orderer's envionment` in your orderer.yaml or docker-compose?
(To make sure that my assumptions are correct, the presence of the peer's log can be clear.)

Comment: @AdityaJoshi `https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/organizations/ccp-template.yaml` this example does not have channel and order information. Apart from that the rest of config is same

Comment: @myeongkilkim, yes you assumptions are correct. There is no problem with network and client connection to the peer. Client application running on docker container is successfully able to fetch the information from the network (peer).  it is exactly the same as here `https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml`

Comment: Client application is written in kotlin/springboot and running on netty server. Not sure client can't connect to orderer using `host.docker.internal` from  client container, but no issue connecting peer. Updated the question with client error stack trace

Comment: `No subject alternative names matching IP address host.docker.internal found`
I see the log. `Subject Alternative Name` exists in the certificate(X.509). The workaround that comes to mind is to first replace the address in your `connection profile` with the address of the common name in the orderer's certificate (like `orderer.example.com`). Of course, if that happens, you should be able to find the domain name. To do this, if a local DNS is built or operated as a fabric&client docker, within the same docker network, the container name can be found as a domain.

Comment: Another way is to add SANS. (I haven't tested that method.) When creating a crypto-config by executing the cryptogen command, it is a problem of the error in the part where you enter SANS as the input host.docker. It is inferred that the error can be resolved by adding internal.

Comment: The last thing that suddenly came to mind is to use `extra_hosts`. If you upload your fabric client to docker, but use docker's extra_hosts option to map orderer.example.com to an address that the orderer container can reach, it seems to be resolved. (Of course, the url of the connection profile is the orderer's domain name. Should be changed to.)

Comment: @myeongkilkim created the network using fabric-ca, so not sure if I can use SANS as it is for cryptogen. When used order.example.com instead of host.docker.internal. I got the below error

Comment: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel mychannel, send transactions failed on orderer OrdererClient{id: 9, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.example.com, url: grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050}. Reason:  timeout after 10000 ms.

Comment: This is network details of orderer container by inspecting, I tried with '172.22.0.5' as well and it didn't work either"7f43486177910502c5f4176b66e2a2e5f84f10fd67212d61fdcbdf8045350d82": {
                "Name": "orderer.example.com",
                "EndpointID": "993af1a231af77190725bf641f90360328250e723be98bb0ae286232069e3daa",
                "MacAddress": "",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }

Comment: Also I have added  (127.0.0.1) in configtx.yaml and restarted network, but no use OrdererEndpoints:                            
           - orderer.example.com:7050
            - "127.0.0.1:7050". And when I specify orderer.example.com in the config, Its getting timeout and fiinally returns this exception ```org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.contractexception failed to send transaction to the orderer```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a loopback, it should not go into configtx.yaml. This is because the nodes participating in the channel go to the url written in the transaction/block generated by configtx. In other words, you need to put in an address where you can find the orderer (docker.internal/orderer.example.com, etc.) First of all, it is difficult to answer immediately, and I will answer it tomorrow.

Comment: @myeongkilkim I have brought down the network, removed the volumes in my docker container. As you have mentioned given order.example.com under the orderer url `url: grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050`  in config and made sure that service is in the same network as blockchain's. Then it started working!  Thank-you vey much for helping!